# Obey server_name in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I want nginx/0.7.6 (on debian, i.e. with config files in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`) to serve a site on exactly one subdomain (indicated by the Host header) and nothing on all others. But it staunchly ignores my `server_name` settings?!

In `sites-enabled/sub.domain`:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name sub.domain;
  location / { … }
}
```

Adding a `sites-enabled/00-default` with

```
server {
  listen 80;
  return 444;
}
```

Does nothing (I guess it just matches requests with no Host?)

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *.domain;
  return 444;
}
```

Does prevent `Host: domain` requests from giving results for `Host: sub.domain`, but still treats `Host: arbitrary` as `Host: sub-domain`.

The, to my eyes, obvious solution isn't accepted:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *;
  return 444;
}
```

Neither is

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  return 444;
}
```

Since order seems to be important: renaming `00-default` to `zz-default`, which, if sorted, places it last, doesn't change anything. But debian's main config just includes `*`, so I guess they could be included in some arbitrary file-system defined order?

---

This returns no content when `Host:` is not `sub.domain` as expected, but still returns the content when `Host` is completely missing. I thought the first block should handle exactly that case!? Is it because it's the first block?

```
server {
  listen 80;
  return 444;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ~^.*$;
  return 444;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to define a default server in nginx is by setting the `default_server` flag (in 0.7, it's just `default`) on the server's [listen](http://nginx.org/r/listen) statement.  `server_name _;` doesn't mean anything special.  nginx also does not sort globbed filenames, so the files aren't guaranteed to be included in any specific order.

```
server {
  listen 80 default;
  return 444;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using this as the first block matches all request not matched by any following `server_name: sub.domain` block. No Idea why `_` doesn't work, using a regex seems hackish.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ~^.*$ "";
  return 444;
}
```

i.e. `~^.*$` matches all `Host:` headers, `""` matches no `Host:` header being sent.

Comment: Because you're running an antique 0.7 version of nginx. That hasn't been supported in years. If you insist on using debian, please do yourself a favor and use the [dotdeb](http://www.dotdeb.org/) repositories.

Comment: yeah, I knew debian was slow, but I just didn't expect a "stable" release from 2012 to come with a version from 2008… (I have to rely on debian & backports though, since my virtual server has an ancient kernel current libc-releases don't even support anymore…)

Answer (score -1):

The default virtual host should contain:

```
server_name _;
```

[This is a catch-all](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) that will match any host name not specified in any other `server_name` directive.

You are also correct when you note that when `server_name` is missing, the block matches only requests without a `Host:` header.

Note that this probably won't work on nginx 0.7.x, which is antique and horribly out of date, and for which many things have changed. If you insist on using debian, please do yourself a favor and use the [dotdeb](http://www.dotdeb.org/) repositories to keep current with software such as nginx, MySQL, and PHP, for which it's critical to update much more rapidly than Debian does.

Comment: With `server{listen 80; return 444;} server{listen 80; server_name _; return 444}` it still answers for no `Host:`, `Host: arbitrary` and `Host: wrong.domain`, just not for `Host: domain`.

Comment: Do you have a `server` block defined for `domain`? You never mentioned creating one.

Comment: no, just `sub.domain`, I thought I could create a true catch-all block and then just supply `server` blocks for the (sub)domains I'm actually trying to serve. (Success, see my answer)

Comment: I'm just realizing that my Debian Stable version of nginx is 0.7, I just assumed it was recent enough to skip the historic blocks in the manual m(

Comment: server_name _ doesn't define a default server.  From the documentation you linked: "There is nothing special about this name, it is just one of a myriad of invalid domain names which never intersect with any real name. Other invalid names like “--” and “!@#” may equally be used."